# How to change the format output from ftl

Tags: geoserver

I have have a view in GeoServer from PostgreSQL and I like the default free marker template output in Layer preview but I would like to change it to where to have column names of `Field name` and `Field Value`.

Since the default content.ftl is iterating through and outputting all the content horizontally is there a easy way to make the table print vertically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [GeoServer Freemarker tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html):

```
<ul>
<#list features as feature>
  <li><b>Type: ${type.name}</b> (id: <em>${feature.fid}</em>):
  <ul>
  <#list feature.attributes as attribute>
    <#if !attribute.isGeometry>
      <li>${attribute.name}: ${attribute.value}</li>
    </#if>
  </#list>
  </ul>
  </li>
</#list>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes I read through that tutorial and that format is what I am after but I was more interested in keeping the information in table format rather then a list.

Comment: Never Mind I figured it out.I took the list and placed it in html table tags....I think my brain was fried by the end of the day and just could not think Thank you for your Help